# Get related Usb letter from smartcard

Tags: c#, smartcard

I've a smartcard reader embedded on removable USB drive.

I'm capable to get many info about smartcard reader, but none of them in order to achieve the related USB drive letter. it isn't seems exist any relation between smartcard reader and USB drive.

Is there some way to retrieve usb letter starting from smartcard reader info? Note that for that I'm using WMI and Net.Sf.Pkcs11 .Net dll too.

Comment: Does a smartcard have a letter? You mean a drive-letter? Or do you mean a memorycard like compact-flash or SD-card?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now: it is a combined USB-drive/smarcard reader device :) In this case, you'll have to look starting from the USB node, and try to enumerate the devices from the same USB node. Never done this before, but you might want to take a look at the source code of [USBView](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/USBView-sample-application-e3241039)

Comment: Yes, it's a combined USB drive/smartcard reader device. However, I've looked posted link but it's not helpful for me. Have you other suggestions?

Comment: Smart Cards, as in credit-cards like devices containing a processor or protected memory don't get assigned a drive letter. The reason for this is that they don't have file structures like FAT embedded on them, and that you've got to perform authentication and the like. If you are talking about memory sticks and flash memory such as SD-cards: that's not called a smart card reader.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as an USB letter either; I think the hubs and devices have unique ID's, but I've never seen single letters. *drives* get assigned a letter, and then only after mounting, and only within Windows.

Comment: So, is not there any way to retrieve usb device which embed my smartcard reader?

Comment: ..If Window OS is able to recognize in a single time smartcard reader and USB after plug in it, that means that exist some way to get usb device from smartcard and/or vice-versa. Well, I can get all information about smartcard reader and usb device, but nothing relation between them and it's just what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you are trying to achieve, it should certainly be possible to get the USB ID of the smard card reader, but then what?

Comment: Ok. I've a smartcard reader embedded in a usb pen drive with a digital certificate. My application interface with smartcard in order to sign pdf document and to insert an image on final pdf doc. A prerequisite required by customer, is that image file must be inside usb pen, otherwise no-one user can choose any image file to applying on pdf doc. So, I must necessarily go up to usb pen device from smartcard and force user to choose an image starting from usb root.